# Windows 8 - Request camera permission after it's denied

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm writing an app that needs to use the camera.  The first time you do this, it asks the user for permission to use the camera.

If they click "Block" is there anyway through the application to re-request that permission?  Or do they have to uninstall and reinstall the app?

Comment: Can you not write a check for this so that if they click `Block`, there's a message that informs them why it's needed, and offer them the chance again?

Comment: @CL4PTR4P: As I understand it, that is precisely Nick's question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh768223.aspx#what_if_access_to_a_device_is_turned_off_), your app should tell them how to turn the capability back on and not force the permission window to show.

> Your app should tell the user that the capability is turned off, and
> that they can enable the capability by using the app's settings.
>
> "Your  is currently turned off. To change your
>  setting, open the settings charm and tap
> permissions. Then  to start using 
> again."

And from the additional guideline list:

> Don't programmatically try to launch the Permissions page in the
> Settings charm

So simply display a message explaining how to re-enable the permission if they want to use that feature. The user won't have to uninstall and reinstall the app to change its permissions.

Comment: Man, I've been using Windows 8 since Dev Previews and I forgot about the permissions under the setting charm.